# Change Url Flutter Format

Tags: flutter, url

i have url string in flutter like this,

```
"https://qa-mamama.com/1.1/login"
```

how can i make my url to like this ?

```
"https:\/\/qa-mamama.com\/1.1\/login"
```

Before, i try encode to handle this, but not working
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with 'replaceAll' method.

```
void main() {
  String a = "https://qa-mamama.com/1.1/login";
  
  String b = a.replaceAll('/', '\\/');
  print(a);
  print(b);
}
```

[image]